# Return two identical rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an ordering system that can have multiple receipts related to one order. I recently ran into a query as follows that produced an undesirable result.

```
SELECT info FROM orders WHERE id IN (1, 2, 2) ORDER BY FIELD (id, 1, 2, 2);
```

Is there a way to return the row for order #2 twice? As of right now the query returns row one then row two as expected; however, in this particular instance returning row #2 twice is needed.

The tables are roughly as follows (I know it isnt totally valid MySQL, just for illustration):

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    id int(),
    info VARCHAR(),
)

CREATE TABLE links (
    orderid int(),
    receiptid int()
)

CREATE TABLE receipts (
    id int(),
    otherinfo VARCHAR(),
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding the situation correctly, you have  two entries in the orders table
but orderId 2 is listed twice in the links table.  If that is correct, then what you want is:

```
select o.info from orders o
inner join links l on o.id = l.orderid
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return the row twice, then filtering in the `where` clause is not what you want.  You can do this by filtering using a `join`:

```
SELECT o.info
FROM orders o join
     (select 1 as id union all select 2 union all select 2
     ) ids
     on o.id = ids.id
ORDER BY FIELD (o.id, 1, 2, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you coul make use of a [UNION ALL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Something like

```
SELECT info FROM orders WHERE id IN (1, 2)
UNION ALL
SELECT info FROM orders WHERE id IN (2)
```